# Using the digits 2, 3, 4 make an expression for 30

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

Write an expression using exactly one 2, exactly one 3, and exactly one 4 
to make 30.

### For each problem, you must use all three of these:

- Division
- Factorials (just for regular factorial use, no special factorials)
- Parentheses (They would be required to show the factorial of a factorial,
  as in (X!)!, for instance.)

### Other Rules For Clarification:

- No other digits may be used.
- No other operations may be used.
- No concatenation of digits is permitted.
- Your solution must require the use of parentheses to be 
  valid.  If all of the parentheses 
  can be removed, and the expression still equals 30, then that solution is not valid.

I am intending one solution for this problem.

Comment: Why $x!!$ won't be valid?

Comment: @ Epik K.  - I don't want that to be confused with the double factorial.  And my rules are just using the regular factorials when it comes to the "!" symbol.

Comment: I prefer to be really mentioned, not with `@`, but with `@ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος`.

Comment: @Έρικ Κωνσταντόπουλος, I copied and pasted your name just now.

Comment: You also need to remove spaces, then you're fine. I won't change my name for that. Copy-Paste then space removal. `@Έρικ` is a mention, as `@Έρι` is, but I prefer the full name to appear.

Comment: No, I do not need to remove spaces.  Your username does not have a space between the two names.  So, anyone addressing you is to type your username just as the spacing shows.  If you don't want any spacing in your username, then you must change your username to reflect that.

Comment: There is a space: `Έρικ<-space->Κωνσταντόπουλος`

Comment: Yes, I pointed out that has a space. Then, it did make sense that earlier you wanted "@ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος," which has no spaces.

Answer (score 10):

Here's a solution:

> $((3! \div{2})!)! \div{4!}  $

Or written a little more clearly:

> $((\frac{3!}{2})!)! \div{4!}$